# How to call an activity method (not start) from ItemizedOverlay?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I use MapActivity with my own class extending ItemizedOverlay. I would like to achieve a result described below:

When user tap an element on map I would like to get the data from tapped item (title, snippet) and pass it to the MapActivity. 
In MapActivity I have a method that handle that data but I do not know how can I pass that data across application (maybe I should use Handler?)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you pass data by starting Activities using the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) system. Here is a good SO question about it:

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: But why I have to start a new activity if the target activity would still be the same MapActivity? ;)